# Copy specific ranges from multiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a monthly task where I have to open a saved file containing data in multiple tabs with different sheet names and copy the data into a pre-saved workbook (E.g., Master Workbook).  The data in the open file is in different columns and needs to be pasted to various columns in one worksheet in the master workbook.  Is there a macro that can assist with this?  I have prepared this code below, but not sure how to have it loop through the multiple tabs and how to paste the data in different columns in the master workbook.

```
Sub GetJEData()
Dim M As Long, o As Long, v As Long, y As Long, Z As Long
Dim filetoOpen As Variant
Dim Openbook As Workbook
M = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
o = Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
v = Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
y = Range("S" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Z = Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
filetoOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your file & Import Range", 
FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls")
If filetoOpen <> False Then
Set Openbook = Application.Workbooks.Open(filetoOpen)

Worksheets("Journal Entry").Range("C18:C" & M).Copy _
Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Journal Entry").Range("E14:E1000")

Worksheets("Journal Entry").Range("H18:H" & o).Copy _
Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Journal Entry").Range("L14:L1000")


Worksheets("Journal Entry").Range("K18:K" & v).Copy _
Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Journal Entry").Range("J14:J1000")


Worksheets("Journal Entry").Range("S18:S" & y).Copy _
Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Journal Entry").Range("AB14:AB1000")

Worksheets("Journal Entry").Range("O18:O" & Z).Copy _
Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Journal Entry").Range("Z14:Z1000")

End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Comment: If you do not know (you do not explain) what to be copied, where from and where, how to understand something from a **not working as you want piece of  code**?

Comment: How many sheets in Openbook need to be read ? A few probably use `If/Elseif` blocks but for many use `Select Case`. Assuming each sheet is a different layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work: using a helper sub to do the actual copying.

```vb
Sub GetJEData()
    
    Dim filetoOpen As Variant, wb As Workbook, wsDest As Worksheet, pasteRow As Range
    
    filetoOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for your file & Import Range", _
                                             FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*),*xls")
    If filetoOpen = False Then Exit Sub
    
    Set pasteRow = ThisWorkBook.Worksheets("Journal Entry").Rows(14) 'paste to this row
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(filetoOpen)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With wb.Worksheets("Journal Entry")
        DoCopy .Range("C18"), pasteRow.Columns("E"), True
        DoCopy .Range("H18"), pasteRow.Columns("L"), True
        DoCopy .Range("K18"), pasteRow.Columns("J"), True
        DoCopy .Range("S18"), pasteRow.Columns("AB"), True
        DoCopy .Range("O18"), pasteRow.Columns("Z"), True
    End With
    'next sheet (eg)
    With wb.Worksheets("Other sheet")
        DoCopy .Range("A16"), pasteRow.Columns("A"), True
        DoCopy .Range("B16"), pasteRow.Columns("B"), True
    End With
    
End Sub

'Copy column of cells starting at cell `srcStart`, to the last-occupied cell in that column,
'  and paste to `destCell`
'Optionally only copy cell values
Sub DoCopy(srcStart As Range, destCell As Range, Optional ValuesOnly As Boolean = False)
    Dim cLast As Range
    With srcStart.Worksheet
        Set cLast = .Cells(.Rows.Count, srcStart.Column).End(xlUp) 'last cell in column
        If cLast.Row >= srcStart.Row Then  'check there's any data to copy
            If ValuesOnly Then 'only copying cell values?
                arr = .Range(srcStart, cLast).Value
                destCell.Resize(UBound(arr, 1), UBound(arr, 2)).Value = arr
            Else
                .Range(srcStart, cLast).Copy destCell
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tim - Thank you for your response.  Quick question: How would this work for 3 tabs named Journal Entry, Journal Entry - Rev, Journal - Entry Rev(2)?  Would it just loop through these sheets and copy the data into one tab?

Comment: You only showed copying between two tabs, so I'm not sure if you're copying data from all 3 source sheets to the same destination sheet, or to different sheets?  If to the same sheet then follow the pattern above - add a `With` block for each source sheet in the opened workbook.

Comment: Yes I did only show between two tabs.  However, I would need to copy between a few more sometimes.  In any case, I will add the with for each source sheet as you indicated.  Thanks!!

Comment: Please flag as "Accepted" if this fixed your problem, to help anyone coming along later with a similar question.

Comment: Hi -  The code works just fine.  However, one more question:  If the columns in the source workbook are blank it brings in the column header from the source workbook.  Is there a workaround that I can use to avoid this?

Comment: I made an edit to check that the "last cell" is at least at or below the "first cell"

Comment: This is the last question promise!  How would you get it to copy values only if this is what is needed?  Last question!!

Comment: OK  -see edit above.  Added optional parameter to switch to copying only cell values.

Comment: Quick Question: If I wanted to use the above code without the file picker. Meaning I just wanted it to run based upon an already open workbook to copy from, how would I go about tweaking the code?

Comment: That sounds like a new question.